# How to save values in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm a new beginner in creating android app.

I tried to create an temperature conversion app using an online guide.
(http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html#tutorialtemperature)

I would like to know if it is possible to store the values that I entered as inputs previously in step 18.8 and then display the values in a table format in another page of the app.

If it is possible, could you guide me on how to store the values?

Thank you.

(I'll clarify if any additional info is needed.)

Edit:

I intend to write the temperature values (that are keyed in) into a text file.

The following codes are from the website.

MainActivity.class

```
package com.vogella.android.temperatureconverter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private EditText text;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputValue);

  }

  // this method is called at button click because we assigned the name to       the
  // "OnClick" property of the button
  public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
      RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
      RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton)           findViewById(R.id.radio1);
      if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
  }

  float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
  if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
    text.setText(String
        .valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
    celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
    fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
  } else {
    text.setText(String
        .valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
    fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
    celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
  }
  break;
    }
  }

}
```

Utility.class

```
package com.vogella.android.temperatureconverter;

public class ConverterUtil {
  // converts to celsius
  public static float convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit) {
    return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
  }

  // converts to fahrenheit
  public static float convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celsius) {
    return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
  }
} 
public void writedata(String data) {
          //BufferedWriter out = null;

      try{

          FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("outputfile.txt"));
          out.write(ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue.getBytes());
          out.close();  

            } 
}
```

(I have modified the Utility code from the website to include the write file method.)

But my program is not working. I'm not sure if my code to write to text file is wrong. 
Also, I don't know where to access the textfile.

I'm a newbie in writing to text files. Hope you can guide me through. Thanks.

Comment: If you store every input in a SQL database, then you can.

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish this. Ideally, you need to try a few and then come back if you have issues.

Comment: @durgadevi1 Post what you have tried till now to get more help.

Comment: You can look for SharedPreferences ,Sqlite , Eventbus or intent extras. There are tons of possible states. I dont know which is ideal for you. Just try and come here with more specific question and with code.

Comment: I need to write the values to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

To permanently store the values you can store it in sqlite-database which  is supported by the database or you can write it the memory of the device using inputstream or you can save it in shared preference but in your case you only want to pass the input by the user without saving it so you can put the float to the intent used to call the activity like so:

```
intent.putExtra("tag",value)
```

then in next activity get that result in by calling

```
getIntent().getFloatExtra("tag", float defaultValue);
```

where "tag" = key of the variable and defaultValue it the value used when for the "tag" key there will be no result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: No issues. Please mark this as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the Data from One Activity to another Activity Using Intent.

```
Intent otherActivityIntent = new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class);
otherActivityIntent.putExtra("key","tempratureValue");
startActivity(otherActivityIntent);
```

In other Activity:

in onCreate()

```
String temprature = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply